# Zend Framework, Doctrine 2 @ManyToOne

Tags: zend-framework, doctrine-orm, many-to-one

I basicky followed this http://www.zendcasts.com/one-to-many-with-doctrine-2/2011/03/ tutorial to the step (source codes can be downloaded from there). And everything works just fine, so I got 2 Entities - Purchase and User. If I query User everything is fine, but if I query Purchase, like so:

```
$entityManager->createQuery('select p from ZC\Entity\Purchase p where p.id = 1')->execute();
```

I will get an Fatal error:

```
Fatal error: require() [function.require]: Failed opening required 'C:\xampp\htdocs\CoChces\application/../library/CC/Entity/Proxy\CCEntityCategoryProxy.php' (include_path='C:\xampp\htdocs\CoChces\application/../library;C:\xampp\htdocs\CoChces\library;.;C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in C:\xampp\htdocs\CoChces\library\Doctrine\ORM\Proxy\ProxyFactory.php on line 85
```

But if i comment this lines in Purchase:

```
 /**
 *
 * @var User
 * @ManyToOne(targetEntity="User")
 * @JoinColumns({
 *  @JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 * })
 */
private $user;
```

Everithing works just fine. So there must be some kind of problem with @ManyToOne annotation. Anyone know what to do with it? Perhaps some workaround?

Thanks a lot for answers..

I'm using PHP 5.3.8

Comment: Which version of PHP are you using? Doctrine 2 requires PHP 5.3...

Comment: Yes I'm using PHP 5.3 I can query ManyToMany with easy, but ManyToOne and OneToOne seems to be the problem..

Comment: Just for the record, many of the zendcasts videos are just plain wrong, or leave out details, causing the final code to not even work properly.

Comment: Feel like I should defend Zendcasts here, as I've found it to be a really valuable resource in spite of code errors, etc. Jon L. (the presenter) doesn't pretend to be the all-knowing expert, and quite a few times he's corrected himself in later episodes when he finds a better way of doing something. He's just a guy trying to figure this stuff out like the rest of us. Watching someone go through that process is actually very valuable and reassuring. For a semi-newbie like me, it's great to learn from someone like Jon who's willing to share his learning process with the rest of us.

Comment: @cantera25 I feel the same way about Zendcasts..John is great for sharing all the cast with us, can't imagine how much work that must be..

Answer (score 0):

Couple of things...

1. Your annotation syntax doesn't appear to be correct. Try

   ```
   /**
    * @var User
    * @ManyToOne(targetEntity="User")
    */
   private $user;
   ```

   `@JoinColumns` doesn't appear anywhere in the documentation. Also, the `@JoinColumn` annotation is redundant as you are using the default values. See http://www.doctrine-project.org/docs/orm/2.1/en/reference/association-mapping.html#many-to-one-unidirectional
2. Your DQL query references the `ZC` namespace root but the error message says `CC`. Which is correct?

Comment: Thanks for suggestions, but it didn't fix the problem, I'm guessing there is problem with outdated Doctrine 2 libraries, John is using "2.0.0RC2" so it had to be a bug back than, or there is a bug in the "Bisna"(also outdated) glue that makes ZF1 work with Doctrine2.. will try both and I'll write solution if I will find one..

Comment: @user987220 I'd start by at least using the latest Doctrine 2.1 stable release. There shouldn't be any issues with the Bisna application resource plugin. Any comment on point #2

Comment: Well the problem was with the Bisna resource, it was outdated, there can be found a new one on guilhermeblanco github here: https://github.com/guilhermeblanco/ZendFramework1-Doctrine2 And as for configuration of it I would suggest: http://www.kurttest.com/zfa/bisna.html In other word, problem solved, thanks everyone

Comment: @user987220 Ah, I thought that would have been the one you were using already. Glad you got it sorted.